# Xamarin forms with ReactiveUI for calling the API request

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httprequest, reactiveui

I have Xamarin Forms application, on my landing page ViewModel Constructor
I have Async Void GetStationMarkets() method which Calling 2 API requests.

```
Example:
public LandingPageViewModel()
{
 Task.Run(() => GetStationsMarkets());
}

async void GetStationMarkets()
{
 await GetAsyncStations();
 await GetAsyncMarkets();
}
```

Since using the async void is not a good practice for calling API and initialize the calling of API in the constructor because it may cause screen my freeze.
How can I use ReactiveUI to remove the async void to call in the constructor and to make sure that the Landing Page will not freeze and will not cause any problem in the future? (edited)

Comment: Have a look how MS does it https://github.com/microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps/blob/master/src/BikeSharing.Clients.Core/ViewModels/MyRidesViewModel.cs (examine InitializeAsync method)

Answer (score 0):

ReactiveUI can be used to call commands in response to state changes.  So when the ViewModel is initialized, ReactiveUI can execute a command to go retrieve data.

An example of how this is done is here [GoReactive](https://github.com/RLittlesII/demo/blob/26121d87330642f68113be5b0162feee51343660/reactiveui/dotnet-conf/src/GoReactive/GoReactive/Load/LoadData.xaml.cs#L21-L26)